# How can I find out which function is greater problem

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inequality

I asked a similar question before but I got no answer so I will try my luck again with a different one.

> We have the following function
> $$f(x)=2\ln(x)-\frac{c}{x}$$ where $c$ is a positive number.
> Which is greater?

> - $f(e)$
> - $f(\pi)$
> - they equal
> - we cannot determine because we don't know the value of $c$.

What I tried was:

I tried finding the derivative first , and I got $f'(x)=$$\frac{2x+c}{x^2}$ , then I tried to find the maximum or minimum thought it might give me a lead I compared $f'(x)=0$ and got that Maxima/minima is $\frac{c}{2}$ I don't know if this info will help but I kept going to put the value I found in the original function $f($$\frac{c}{2})$ ,  $f($$\frac{c}{2})=2\ln(c)-\ln(2)-2$ we know that this point can be a minimum or maximum but as I said I don't know if this info will help..

I also tried moving the graph a on desmos and found out the as long as c is positive $f(\pi)$ is greater
but I wanna know why .. I cant seem to figure it out.

I need help and advice on how to approach these type of questions, please I would appreciate it if anyone can give me tips for questions like that , the final answer is not that important.

thank you.

Comment: try and compute $f(\pi) - f(e)$. The resulting expression is independant of $c$, so that you can conclude regardless of the calue of $c$.
Oh and by the way, there is a mistake in you derivative evaluation.

Comment: Did you mean $f(x) = 2ln(x) - \frac{c}{x}$? (since that's what derivative would be suggesting)

Comment: @radekzak Sorry for the mistake you are right

Comment: You should not accept my answer yet. It was for your original problem. I'm fixing for the new one.

Comment: @mrsamy I also got confused and for a minute thought that the original(which is a mistake) was my actual problem , my bad people I edited the post and sorry for the English mistakes as well it is hard to translate (atleast for me) and hard to describe the math problems

Comment: @Adamrk:  I now have edited my answer. Both versions included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>This is for your original version of the problem, where $f(x)=2\ln(x)-\frac{c}{2}$.</sup>

You are making the problem more complicated than necessary.

Note that the logarithm is an increasing function and $e<\pi$. So you have $\ln(e)<\ln(\pi)$, which implies that $2\ln(e)+C<2\ln(\pi)+C$, where $C$ is *any* constant.

---

Now your problem is changed to
$$
f(x)=2\ln(x)-\frac{c}{x}\quad (c>0)
$$

Taking the derivative, for any $x>0$, you have (since $c>0$)
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2}{x}+\frac{c}{x^2}>0
$$
So $f$ is increasing for $x>0$ and thus $f(e)<f(\pi)$.